# Server error after modifying current httprequest

Tags: c#, asp.net, sharepoint, httprequest, server-error

I've been at this for too long, and I'm sure somebody out there will be able to point out my error in a matter of seconds.

My company has an ipad app that downloads sales materials for our salesmen (powerpoints, videos, etc.).  All of the resources are in a document library inside SharePoint.  Instead of making the document library public (and less secure), I've created an .aspx page with a web part on it that fetches the documents.  The ipad app contacts the .aspx page and sends two queries: "token" and "document".  The token is essentially a password so the web part knows it is coming from the ipad app.  If the token is correct, the web part will fetch whatever document is specified.

**Here is my problem**.  The document gets fetched and delivered just like it should, but then if I try to download another document, or navigate anywhere else on the server for that matter, I get a server error.  I have to close the browser (aka end the session).

**The error I'm getting is explained here**: http://blog.tylerholmes.com/2008/07/problem-with-sharepoint.html

I don't want to use the fix on that blog however, because I know that my code is causing the problem, and I want to fix the root of the issue.

My web part code is below:

```
protected override void CreateChildControls()
    {
        string toRender = string.Empty;
        SPWeb webInUserContext = SPContext.Current.Web;
        SPSite SiteInUserContext = SPContext.Current.Site;
        Guid webGuid = webInUserContext.ID;
        Guid siteGuid = SiteInUserContext.ID;

         //gives visitors the authority to see the dam data
        SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
        {
            using (SPSite site = new SPSite(siteGuid))
            {
                using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(webGuid))
                {
                    using (DAM dam = new DAM())
                    {
                        String mystring = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
                        //If the request contains the correct token
                        if (mystring.ToString().Contains("REgrgg0434GgdLk6"))
                        {
                            //Get the document data into a byte array
                            byte[] buf = new byte[0];
                            using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
                            {
                                //Right now I'm just hard-coding a document url for testing, rather than
                                //getting it from the url query
                                String url = "http://web-dev/sites/damedit/DocLibrary/document.ppt";
                                System.Net.CredentialCache cc = new System.Net.CredentialCache();
                                cc.Add(new Uri(url), "NTLM", new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain"));
                                wc.Credentials = cc;
                                buf = wc.DownloadData(url);
                            }

                            //Rewrite the current response so that it contains the document
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"document.ppt\"");
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(buf);
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
                            HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        base.CreateChildControls();
    }
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the error you linked to is your error? I ask this because the iPad (or more specifically, Mobile Safari) has big problems handling the 401,401,200 response chain that NTLM requires.

Comment: Yes, because I haven't even tested on the iPad app yet.  I'm just typing the URL into a browser to make sure the web part gets and delivers the document correctly.  The whole goal of this web part is to handle all the authentication so the iPad app doesn't have to.

Answer (score 0):

Alright I've found the solution.  All I had to do was remove the **HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();** line.  It turns out that the next line of code, **HttpContext.Current.Response.End();** does the same thing as the Flush method, it sends response output to the client.  For some reason, the server doesn't like it when you call both these methods.  Hope this helps someone!